# What really happened to Gwen Stacy?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-amazing-spider-man-2

At the end of **The Amazing Spider man 2** Gwen Stacy looked dead, but in her funeral the camera did not show her grave, we just saw Peter Parker and her family crying, which give us a thought about may be she did not die. Is she dead for sure or not? Please base your answers on strong facts.

Answer (score 4):

[From the word of god:](http://www.ew.com/article/2014/05/08/spider-man-marc-webb-gwen-stacy)

> As many have predicted for nearly a year, Gwen Stacy (Emma Stone) **does indeed fall to her death in The Amazing Spider-Man 2, much as she did in Amazing Spider-Man #121 – a comic which, appropriately enough, is known as “The Night Gwen Stacy Died.”** But regardless of speculation and source material that dates back nearly four decades, some audiences were still shocked to see Peter Parker’s first love come to such a terrible end. “I’ve poked my head into theaters in L.A. for that moment just to hear people gasp,” ***director Marc Webb*** tells EW. “It’s fascinating. People just don’t believe it.”
>
> Webb understands. He felt much the same way when Gwen Stacy was killed off in the comic. “It stayed with me in a profound way. It broke me. I was anxious and curious to explore it on the screen. **From the very beginning I planned on doing it,” he says. “For me, everything in the movie was built around that moment. There’s a cost to being a hero.”**

And since the franchise has died to allow it to be rebooted, any speculation on ASM 3 is just that, speculation. So Gwen is dead and buried.

Of course, comic Gwen was eventually cloned 2 years after her original comic death, as part of the Clone Saga. And died. And resurrected. And rinse, lather repeat as comic characters are known to do.

Comment: I didn't minded either if peter died with her.

Comment: @AnkitSharma what, like kill peter, and start ASM 3 with him waking up not knowing what happen, and finding another peter and freaking out half way through the film? Hmm, Clone Saga goodness.

Comment: I mean end the bad franchise without cliffhanger. Anyways that was a bad joke.